# How can I apply a LUT to tiles in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, lookup-tables

I have an image that is tiled that I display in leaflet.  I would like the user to be able to select different options to apply pixel math on these tiles and then use look up table to display the corresponding color.  Detailed example given below.

ex:

**image name**  | **pixel coordinate** |  **RGB values**

tile0.png | (0,0) | [100, 200, 200]

then the user will select option A which will do...R + G and divide by 2 then look up this value in a table to apply a new color.

(100 + 200) / 2 = 150.  Use the look up table to find 150, it says change that pixel to [100, 100, 100]

Comment: A LUT is a pretty specific thing in graphics land, were you talking about an actual LUT (e.g. an 8 or 33 point cube LUT that models the entire RGB color transform) or were you using the term for some custom, "not the same as the graphics  industry standard LUT" color transform?